# automount USB stick ext4 on Fedora XFCE

Tags: fedora, xfce, ext4, automounting

I have USB stick with two partitions VFAT and ext4. When I plug in stick, VFAT partition is RW automounted but ext4 partition is RO for user because is mounted under root:root

```
# df -T
/dev/sdc5  ext4 11093936  27736 10499316   1% /run/media/username/My-USBLinux
/dev/sdc1  vfat  4087992 357920  3730072   9% /run/media/username/MyUSB
```

Mount directory:

```
# ls -l /run/media/username
drwxr-xr-x 3 username username 4096  1. led  1970 MyUSB
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 21. čen 11.19 My-USBLinux
```

Is any solution to automont ext4 under username ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *chown* to change the owner of the */run/media/username/My-USBLinux* folder

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.